# Python to C# code .How could be converted

Tags: python, c#, if-statement

I am trying to convert piece of Python code into C# but unfortunately I am stuck on a certain peace . How can I convert this  part from Python code into C# code

```
if not (town in ("Bansko", "Borovets") and option in ("noEquipment", "withEquipment",)) and not (
        town in ("Varna", "Burgas") and option in ("noBreakfast", "withBreakfast")):
    print(f'Invalid input!')
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: why use an `f` string when there are no fields in the string?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YLAUjN64 this is my option in C#

Comment: why don't you edit your question?

Comment: use `List<String>.Contains()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve? And by that I don't mean that you want to convert python to c#. Tip: edit your post if you want to add something, that makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
var citylist1 = new List<string>() { "Bansko", "Borovets" };
var citylist2 = new List<string>() {"Varna", "Burgas"};
// Do the same for options..

if ( !(citylist1.Contains(town) && optionList1.Contains(option)) &&
     !(citylist2.Contains(town) && optionList2.Contains(option)))
{
   Console.WriteLine("error");
}
```

Comment: i dont think its 100% correct but that systematics, marked up gives OP the idea

Comment: I was just giving the overall idea of how the algorithm should be structured. In terms of coding structure, it should be 90% correct, just needs some simple testing.